# How to persist device id or any id after extension is re-installed

Tags: browser, storage, browser-extension

I have a browser extension which stores a client-id in local storage upon installation in background.html page. Now if i reinstall the extension the client-id is gone from the local storage of background.html. So i need some implementation such that either that id can persist on re-installation or if i can store the browser id or something as such in my database and check with that on re-installation. Can anyone help me on this?

I tried using cookies and cache storage its not working for me.